# Android. Style for DialogFragment not working

Tags: android, android-theme, android-dialogfragment, android-styles, android-module

I have project with two modules: app and design_utils. Inside my app module I use DialogFragment. I need to set style for my DialogFragment views from design_utils module. In turn, the design_utils module contains the file themes with all the styles I need.

When I directly try to set the styles for the views (in xml), it's not working. Only works if I additionally set the style (with primary, secondary colors and etc) from the design_utils module for my activity in the manifest:
<activity

```
    android:name=".TestActivity"    
    android:resizeableActivity="false"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.DesignUtils"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
```

However, I don't need to set this theme for the activity, I would like to set for my DialogFragment only. And so here my code:

```
override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
    val dialogThemeContext = ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.Theme.DesignUtils)
    return Dialog(
        dialogThemeContext,
        R.style.CustomAlertDialogStyle_Test
    ).apply {
        setContentView(R.layout.dialog_test)

    }
}
```

However, this doesn't work. The styles that I apply from the design_utils module to my views inside the dialog do not work. Please tell me what could be the problem.

Comment: Have to tried overriding getTheme() method in your dialog fragment?

Comment: @Malik Bilal, yes not working too(